# Class java.util.List has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase database for my android app.
I have entity:

```
   public class Goal  implements Serializable {
        private double averageSpeed;
        private long duration;
        private Date startDate;
        private Date endDate;
        private LinkedList <LatLng> locations;
    ...
    }
```

And I am trying to get those objects from database like this:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Goal goal = dataSnapshot.getValue(Goal.class);
                goalAdapter.add(goal);
            }
```

But then I get the error

> Class java.util.List has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead exception

JSON structure of my database:

```
    {
  "goals" : {
    "-KdPyQTvht4seniKUk6o" : {
      "averageSpeed" : 0,
      "distance" : 0,
      "duration" : 619,
      "endDate" : {
        "date" : 20,
        "day" : 1,
        "hours" : 12,
        "minutes" : 3,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 21,
        "time" : 1487585001328,
        "timezoneOffset" : -120,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "locations" : [ {
        "latitude" : 50.5066025,
        "longitude" : 30.4184
      }, {
        "latitude" : 50.506281,
        "longitude" : 30.4189611
      } ],
      "startDate" : {
        "date" : 20,
        "day" : 1,
        "hours" : 12,
        "minutes" : 2,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 44,
        "time" : 1487584964181,
        "timezoneOffset" : -120,
        "year" : 117
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I change my code to make everything works fine?

Comment: Why are you using a raw `List`?

Comment: I see that you're nesting the linked list. That might not be the best idea. Can you share the JSON structure that you're reading (as text, no screenshot)? You can easily get this by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/).

Comment: I have aded JSON structure to my post. What can be na alternative to nesting linked list?

Answer (score 0):

You're making it more difficult than is necessary. A `GenericTypeIndicator` is only needed when you're retrieving for example a list of goals from a DataSnapshot in one call. If you just need a single goal, you can pass in the class to `getValue()`:

```
Goal goal = dataSnapshot.getValue(Goal.class);
```

While you're at it, you might want to change the `List` to a type-safe collection:

```
private List<Goal> locations;
```